# How do I combine two date fields in Google Data Studio?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-sheets, google-forms, looker-studio

I seek to create a field in Google Data Studio using a CASE statement including a date column and a datetime column. Whenever the date column `Start_Time` is NULL, the datetime column `Given_Timestamp` is not NULL.

#### The issue

Whenever `Start_Time` is not filled, the date for visuals has to be taken from `Given_Timestamp`. I tried the statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN Start_Time IS NULL THEN TODATE(Given_Timestamp, 'DEFAULT_DASH', '%d%m%Y')
  ELSE Start_Time
END
```

(Note that `TODATE(Timestamp,'DEFAULT_DASH','%d%m%Y')` gives the date in the same form as `Start_Time` when listing them in a table visual.)

It throws the error message:

> Failed to parse CASE statement.

What am I missing?

#### Details

In the source Google sheet, `Given_Timestamp` is filled automatically via a Google form. Since the datetime format is no standard in Google Data Studio, I have to import it to Data Studio as a string.

I already tried to convert the datetime column to a date column in a separate field to then use that field in the CASE statement. In this case, there is no error message. However, there seems to be an issue with the resulting field. I can't use it for any visual:

[image: Visual in Google Data Studio when using the resulting field]

Answer (score 2):

You can only use fields which are already created in a CASE statement.

So, in this case, you need to first create calculated field like

`dateFromTimestamp = TODATE(Given_Timestamp, 'DEFAULT_DASH', '%d%m%Y')`

and then in the case statement use this field

```
CASE WHEN Start_Time IS NULL THEN dateFromTimestamp ELSE Start_Time END
```

Comment: I already tried your solution and the error message disappeared. However, the result seems to be a date field filled with only NULLs. I am unable to successfully use the new field for any visual.